# R source function : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I am totally new to R so this question may seem a bit silly to most of you.

I was trying to source a toolbox named `Jags-Ybinom-XnomSsubjCcat-MbinomBetaOmegaKappa.R` however encountered with an error. The codes are listed below:

```
myData = read.csv("D:/Rtools/DBDA2Eprograms/BattingAverage.csv")
source("D:/Rtools/DBDA2Eprograms/Jags-Ybinom-XnomSsubjCcat-MbinomBetaOmegaKappa.R")
```

The data file could be read by R studio, however the toolbox could not. And the error is:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :

 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

Comment: Could you verify that the file is located at `D:/Rtools/DBDA2Eprograms/Jags-Ybinom-XnomSsubjCcat-MbinomBetaOmegaKappa.R`?

Comment: And make sure that you have the name correct. That's exactly the error you would get if there wasn't a file of that exact name.